# Having trouble updating an attribute with an association attached to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have two models here: `Package` and `Status`

Package `belongs_to` status

Status `has_many` packages

So, my Package model has a `status_id` column

In my Packages controller, I've got this method (that receives data from an ajax POST call):

```
def edit_status
  @status = Status.find_by_name(params[:status])
  Package.update(params[:id], :status_id => @status.id)
end
```

But it's weird...I can't get `status_id` to update to save my life. If I change out the `status_id` column for any other column in the record (such as `from_name`) then it works fine.

I feel like I'm taking crazy pills here, but any ideas why this might not be working?

Comment: Is status_id protected from mass assignment? Is the status object being resolved correctly before the Package.update (log its value to the console)?

Comment: status_id is not protected (there are currently not validations/protections in place in the Package or Status models). And the status object is indeed resolving correctly (I've logged it to verify).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need this in the Package Model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :status, :allow_destroy => true
```

More information here: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Answer (score 0):

There may be a validation problem.  I would do a "find" then "update_attributes", which will return "false", letting you know if the record is invalid.

Comment: I've actually tried doing that very thing and I get the exact same outcome.